# Different methods for one ordinary differential eqution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-transform, laplace-transform

I run into a first order ordinary differential equation and am looking for various methods to solve it
$$\frac{d}{dt}q(t) = aq(t)+h(t)\,g(q(t))-1,$$
where $a$ is a constant, $h$ and $g$ are two functions without knowing the explicit form.

Does this kind of differential equation has a name? Any ideas or reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it doesn't have a special name.  If $g$ happens to be a polynomial of degree $\le 3$ it's an Abel equation of the first kind.  And there is no general method to solve it in closed form. For example, the differential equation

$$ y' = y + t y^3 - 1$$

probably does not have close-form solutions.  Maple does not find any, nor does Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Did you mean to write $y'$ (not $y''$)?

Comment: Yes, thanks (editing).